# How to take one number in variable and split it into two numbers that go into seperate variables?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this code:

```
import random

people = random.randrange(1, 11)

fate = random.randint(1, 11)

males = 0

females = 0
```

I would like to take the random number of people, and split that up randomly into two groups of numbers, one group will be male and the other female. So, say I have the number 9 in the people variable, I would then like to split it into two random numbers that equal 9, and then assign them to the variables males and females.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Why not just generate 2 random numbers in certain range?

Comment: Choose a random number up to 9, say A and then calculate 9-A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
males = random.randint(0, people)
females = 9 - males
```

if you meant sum of `males` and `females` should be equal `people`

Comment: `females = people - males`